# Upload blob into MySQL using SQL

Tags: mysql, blob, mariadb, mysql-event

My intention is to upload a blob data into MySQL/MariaDB table field automatically every day. I want to use SQL scheduled events for that. But I cannot sort out the SQL query. The original file is on the web, but even for my local machine, I can't find a query...

When I use the "Add event" in phpMyAdmin, I can browse the file on my local machine. And this is the code which I get automatically generated:

```
INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `data`) 
VALUES (NULL, 0x5b7b0d0a202020202276616c31223a2031312c0d0a202020202276616c32223a2031322c0d0a202020202276616c33223a2031330d0a7d2c207b0d0a202020202276616c31223a2032312c0d0a202020202276616c32223a2032322c0d0a202020202276616c33223a2032330d0a7d2c207b0d0a202020202276616c31223a2033312c0d0a202020202276616c32223a2033322c0d0a202020202276616c33223a2033330d0a7d5d);
```

It's not like `...VALUES (NULL, "C:\data.json");` so I am a bit clueless. Any guidance/examples are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, MySQL/MariaDB does not have any way to reach out into the disk, etc.  You will have to write code in some other language (PHP/Java/...) to open the file, then perform the `INSERT`.

That hex looks like ordinary text (`"val1": 11, utf8:19:19'...`), is there some reason for using hex?  In fact, it looks like `JSON`; is that relevant?

See also `UNHEX()` function.  See various `JSON` functions.  Etc.

Comment: The first 2 sentences explained it. Thank you. That file is was custom created by myself, and yes, it's json. The hex came from the DB when it auto-generated the query. And thanks for references, however in order to use JSON functions, i first must have the file in my db :)

Comment: Then you _probably_ need: `INSERT ... VALUES ( ..., UNHEX("5b7b0d0a202020202276616c31223a20"))`.  Note that the `0x` was removed.